# Как пробросить ошибку в AJAX запросе

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.7

Основная проблема в том, что я по одному полю шлю запросом, так как, если сразу всю форму передам, она сразу вся загорится. Поэтому, с фронта передаю не только подтверждение, а еще и сам Email, остальные поля передаются по одному. Есть проверка на совпадение почты:

```
if ($data['field']) {
  $keys = array_keys($data);

  if (array_key_exists('compare', $data)) {
    if (($data[$keys[0]] === $data[$keys[1]]) ? true : false) {
      return \Validator::make($data, [$keys[0] => $rules[$keys[0]]]);
    } else {
      return ERROR_HERE;
    }
  }

  return \Validator::make($data, [$keys[0] => $rules[$keys[0]]]);
}
```

При несовпадении полей Email и подтверждения нужно выдать ошибку, на фронт. На фронте я ловлю её через метод `.catch()`:

```
validateRequest = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '{{ route('validate') }}',
  data: data,
  success: function() {
    const parentBlock = $('input[name="' + name + '"]').parents('.form-group');
    parentBlock.removeClass('has-error');
    parentBlock.find('#' + name + '_error').text('');
  }
}).catch(function(response) {
  const data = response.responseJSON;
  console.log(data);
  for (let error in data.errors) {
    handle errors
  }
});
```

Пробовал так:

```
response()->json(['errors', 'емаилы не совпадают'], 500);
```

Но что передавал 500 код, что не передавал в запросе - не помогает. Как мне передать с бэка ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать ошибку с бэка (выбросить HTTP исключение) можно при помощи функции-помощника `abort()`, например:

```php
abort(403, 'Unauthorized.', $headers);
```

Но так как вы используете валидацию данных, то было бы правильнее не 500, а 422.

К тому же в Laravel есть правило на подтверждение (совпадение) полей ввода, т.е. одно из полей должно равняться другому. В HTML разметке это выглядит так:

```html
<input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required />
<input type="email" name="email_confirmation" value="" required />
```

При валидации данных добавляете правило `confirmed`:

```php
$rules = [
  'email' => 'required|email|confirmed',
];
```

---

Либо воспользуйтесь методом `validate()`, который автоматически создаёт исключение **Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException**. Если при проверке обнаружатся ошибки, пользователь будет автоматически переадресован, а в случае AJAX-запроса будет возвращён JSON-отклик с кодом 422:

```php
$validator = validator()
  ->make([
      $keys[0] => $data[$keys[0]]
    ], [
      $keys[0] => 'required|email|in:'.$data[$keys[1]],
      // Либо используйте такое правило.
      // $keys[0] => 'required|email|same:'.$keys[1],
  ])
  ->validate(); // Добавить этот метод.
```

Что же касается обработки AJAX запроса на JavaScript, необходимо отлавливать ошибки со статусом 422:

```js
validateRequest = $.ajax({
  // ... остальной код.
  .catch(function (response) {
    if(422 == response.status) {
      const {errors} = response.responseJSON;

      for (let error in errors) {
        console.log(error, errors[error][0]);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: У меня основная проблема в том, что я по одному полю запросом шлю, т.к. если я сразу всю форму передам, она сразу вся загориться. По этому, я с фронта передаю не только подтверждение а еще и сам емаил, остальные поля передаются по одному

Comment: я нашел это throw ValidationException::withMessages([ 'Empty events list']); но это только для 5.8+ а у меня 5.5